# Cuda 6.5 cannot find - libGLU. (On ubuntu 14.04 64 bit)

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I have installed cuda 6.5 on my ubuntu. 
My video card is GTX titan.

When I want to make one of the cuda samples (.../simulations/particles)
I get this message:

```
>>> WARNING - libGLU.so not found, refer to CUDA Samples release notes for how to find and install them. <<<
[@] /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 -o particleSystem.o -c particleSystem.cpp
[@] /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 -o particleSystem_cuda.o -c particleSystem_cuda.cu
[@] /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 -o particles.o -c particles.cpp
[@] /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 -o render_particles.o -c render_particles.cpp
[@] /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 -o shaders.o -c shaders.cpp
[@] /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 -o particles particleSystem.o particleSystem_cuda.o particles.o render_particles.o shaders.o -L../../common/lib/linux/x86_64 -L/usr/lib/nvidia-340 -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGLEW
[@] mkdir -p ../../bin/x86_64/linux/release
[@] cp particles ../../bin/x86_64/linux/release
```

It seems Cuda cannot find LibGLU.

and due to unmet dependencies I cannot install "libglu1-mesa-dev"

I appreciate if you help me.
Thanks

---

Update:
I have Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.
When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
```

I get this:

```
build-essential is already the newest version.
libglu1-mesa is already the newest version.
libx11-dev is already the newest version.
libx11-dev set to manually installed.
libxi-dev is already the newest version.
libxmu-dev is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-glx is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                          libgl-dev
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Maybe there's an 64bit alternative for that package.

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) may help.

Comment: The version of the packages needed, are older than I have I guess

Answer (score 3):

Refer to section [4.7 of the linux getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#runfile-libraries) where it states:

> If you wish to build all the samples, including those with graphical rather than command-line interfaces, additional system libraries or headers may be required. While every Linux distribution is slightly different with respect to package names and package installation procedures, the libraries and headers most likely to be necessary are OpenGL (e.g., Mesa), GLU, GLUT, and X11 (including Xi, Xmu, and GLX).
>
> On Ubuntu, those can be installed as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install freeglut3-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Should be enough to pull all dependencies without causing any conflicts.

I just did this today on Ubuntu 14.04 with Titan X Pascal and CUDA 7.5