# CUDA 8 examples on Ubuntu 16 not finding libGLU, libGL, or libX11

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-16.04

I am using CUDA 8 and I am able to run some of the examples but I can not get any of the visualizations to run. I have gotten them to work in the past, but now I am not able to reproduce the results on the same computer with a fresh install. Mint or Ubuntu.

after a successful install of CUDA I try to `make` the `particles` or `nbody` samples but I get this error:

```
>>> WARNING - libGL.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
>>> WARNING - libGLU.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
>>> WARNING - libX11.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
```

I looked through the [Getting Started guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) but have not found a solution.

I am systematically working through the symbolic links. perhaps someone here can offer a suggestion...

The result of a find request...

```
$ sudo find / -name 'libGLU*'

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
```

I have been trying to create symbolic links to the i386* and x86* libraries but havnt gotten it to work yet.

I am, for example, trying

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/libGLU.so
```

My question now is, which libGLU.so do I need to point "/usr/lib/libGLU.so" to?

```
.a ?
.1?
.1.3.1?
```

x86 or i386? I know my system is 64bit but is CUDA expecting a 32bit library?

Doesn't seem like it should or would but... ?

I have tried the solutions on every SO and other board I can find... the two most relevant are

[Cuda 6.5 cannot find - libGLU. (On ubuntu 14.04 64 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238906/cuda-6-5-cannot-find-libglu-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit)

and

http://kislayabhi.github.io/Installing_CUDA_with_Ubuntu/

which is where this question has existed previously.

Comment: There is [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/993862/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-8-0-missing-required-libraries-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the answer is in the link provided by Robert Crovella.

```
    sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libglfw3-dev libgles2-mesa-dev
```

then

```
GLPATH=/usr/lib make
```

instead of just make

[source of solution](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/993862/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-8-0-missing-required-libraries-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

Thank you Robert.